# Apply Collatz Funtion to solve and print the answer

Tags: programming

Good day to all!

The objective of my task is apply the collatz function for a number `x1` and print the exact number of iterations until `s1`. I want to create a function using `Module`:

```
CollatzFunction[x1_, s1_]:= Module[{.......};
```

Print iterations to `s1`-> "number of iterations"

I barely have an idea using `Nest[]`, but I don't know how to apply `Nest` until the `s1` number is reached.

Please, help in this task, it's just a step towards creating a more complicated function. Thanks.

Comment: s1 might not be in the collatz path of x1...

Comment: Why? @SjoerdC.deVries

Comment: Because the collatz procedure generates a tree and if you start in one branch you will miss numbers in other branches or which are higher up in your own branch.

Answer (score 2):

```
collatz = Switch[Mod[#, 2], 0, #/2, 1, 3 # + 1] &;
count[x1_, s1_] := Length@NestWhileList[collatz, x1, # != s1 &]
count[100, 1]

(* 26 *)
```

Comment: Thanks @belisarius I think this is a good option for my code.

Answer (score 1):

### My solution:

**the definition of Collatz**

```
Collatz[n_Integer?OddQ] := 3 n + 1
Collatz[n_Integer?EvenQ] := n/2
```

**the definition of CollatzSeqLength**

```
CollatzSeqLength[num_Integer,s1_Integer] := 
 Length@NestWhileList[Collatz, num, # != s1 &]
```

**Applying1:**

```
CollatzSeqLength[100, 1]
```

> 26

### Or

```
 CollatzSeqLength2[num_Integer,s1_Integer] :=
  Length@Most@FixedPointList[If[# != s1, Collatz@#, s1] &, num]
```

**Applying2:**

```
CollatzSeqLength2[100, 1]
```

> 26

Comment: Thanks @Tangshutao, I appreciate your answer!! What's the difference between NestWhileList and FixedPointList?

Comment: @MMSci Arturo Ortiz The `Mathematica documentation` has stated clearly.                    `NestWhileList[f,expr,test]` (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html)
generates a list of the results of applying f repeatedly, starting with expr, and continuing `until applying test to the result no longer yields True`.                           `FixedPointList[f,expr]` (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html?q=FixedPointList)
generates a list giving the results of applying f repeatedly, starting with expr, `until the results no longer change`.